# color distortion with illustrator

Tags: color

I want to achieve a kind of color distortion colors, someone help me?

I want to achieve something like the work of Maria groendlund

[image]

Comment: Hi Jorge, thanks for your question. Could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: thanks for the reply, just yesterday I made my own and I'm exploring

very friendly Vincet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you would be best served looking into the mesh tool and different transparency settings. the image you showed has possibly had a lot of work sunk into it.

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
I'll check that option and I'll see if I get results

thank you so much :)